# Ansible: filter a list by its attributes

Tags: jinja2, ansible

I have variable named "network" registered in Ansible:

```yaml
    {
        "addresses": {
            "private_ext": [
                {
                    "type": "fixed",
                    "addr": "172.16.2.100"
                }
            ],
            "private_man": [
                {
                    "type": "fixed",
                    "addr": "172.16.1.100"
                },
                {
                    "type": "floating",
                    "addr": "10.90.80.10"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

Is it possible to get the IP address ("addr") with type="floating" doing something like this?

```
- debug: var={{ network.addresses.private_man | filter type="fixed" | get "addr" }}
```

I know the syntax is wrong but you get the idea.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I've submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/13684) (available in Ansible 2.2+) that will make this kinds of situations easier by adding [jmespath](http://jmespath.org/) query support on Ansible. In your case it would work like:

```
- debug: msg="{{ addresses | json_query(\"private_man[?type=='fixed'].addr\") }}"
```

would return:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "172.16.1.100"
    ]
}
```

Comment: You need to install "jmespath" prior to running json_query filter.

Comment: And I just gave up trying to install jmespath due to Python version differences. It's not as trivial a solution as it looks on Ansible 2.4+

Comment: @StuartWatt you may need pyenv to abstract yourself away from the operating system python version. You can try pyenv, pyenv virtualenvs, or some people prefer pipenv. They will work all the same.

Comment: @Jepper If you need a whole new Python to use Ansible, it's a losing battle. (And I was using pyenv and still had these issues :-)

Comment: Those who have python-related problems: depending on that OS that is running this may require a small trick to help ansible use the right python version. I've had trouble where python 2 + 3 are both installed and Ansible gravitates to v2. you may need to run the following (e.g. if target host is debian):
`sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python2.7 1`
`sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3 2`
`sudo update-alternatives --set python /usr/bin/python3`

(assuming Python2.7 and Python3 are installed)

Answer (score 162):

To filter a list of dicts you can use the [selectattr filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-filters.selectattr) together with the [equalto test](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-tests.eq):

```yaml
network.addresses.private_man | selectattr("type", "equalto", "fixed")
```

The above requires Jinja2 v2.8 or later (regardless of Ansible version).

---

Ansible also [has the tests `match` and `search`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-strings), which take regular expressions:

> `match` will require a complete match in the string, while `search` will require a match inside of the string.

```
network.addresses.private_man | selectattr("type", "match", "^fixed$")
```

---

To reduce the list of dicts to a list of strings, so you only get a list of the `addr` fields, you can use the [map filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-filters.map):

```
... | map(attribute='addr') | list
```

Or if you want a comma separated string:

```
... | map(attribute='addr') | join(',')
```

Combined, it would look like this.

```
- debug: msg={{ network.addresses.private_man | selectattr("type", "equalto", "fixed") | map(attribute='addr') | join(',') }}
```

Comment: If you want them as a list rather than a comma separated string, you can also use: `{{ network.addresses.private_man | selectattr("type", "equalto", "fixed") | map(attribute='addr') | list }}`

Comment: did the link you provide change? i can't find "match" and "search" on that page

Comment: @activedecay Looks like it's gone from that page, yes. The only mention I could find now is on this page: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-strings I updated the link, thanks!

Answer (score 29):

Not necessarily better, but since it's nice to have options here's how to do it using [Jinja statements](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#list-of-control-structures):

```
- debug:
    msg: "{% for address in network.addresses.private_man %}\
        {% if address.type == 'fixed' %}\
          {{ address.addr }}\
        {% endif %}\
      {% endfor %}"
```

Or if you prefer to put it all on one line:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{% for address in network.addresses.private_man if address.type == 'fixed' %}{{ address.addr }}{% endfor %}"
```

Which returns:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "172.16.1.100"
}
```