# Using ansible launch configuration module ec2_lc and securitygroup names versus id

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, ansible

I want to accomplish the following in aws ec2:

- Create security groups using ansible module ec2_group.
- Create a launch configuration using ansible module ec2_lc and attach a security group created earlier.

Now, i want to use the security group names instead of id's because i want to be able to recreate the whole infrastructure with ansible if needed.

Recreating security groups will cause the id of the group to be different. 
But the ec2_lc module only accepts security group id's.

Is there any way i can map a security group id to a name?

I am defining security groups like this:

```
- name: create ec2 group
  ec2_group:
    name: "{{ item.name }}"
    description: "{{ item.description }}"
    vpc_id: "{{ item.vpc_id }}"
    region: "{{ item.region }}"
    state: present
    rules: "{{ item.rules }}"
    rules_egress: "{{ item.rules_egress }}"
  register: sg
```

The launch configuration code looks like this:

```
- name: Create Launch Configuration
  ec2_lc:
    region: "{{ item.region }}"
    name: "{{ item.name }}"
    image_id: "{{ item.image_id }}"
    key_name: "{{ item.key_name }}"
    security_groups: "{{ item.security_groups }}" # how can i refer to specific group_id based on a group name?
    instance_type: "{{ item.instance_type }}"
    user_data: "{{ item.ec2_user_data }}"
    instance_profile_name: "{{ item.instance_profile_name }}"
    assign_public_ip: "{{ item.assign_public_ip }}"
```

Comment: I've submitted a PR that makes possible to mix between security group names and ids. The PR is here: https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/pull/4061

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the ec2_group-facts to query the security groups by name:

```
- ec2_group_facts:
    filters:
      group-name:
      - "{{ sg.name }}"
  register: ec2sgs

- debug:
    msg: "{{ ec2sgs.security_groups | map(attribute='group_id')| list }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

With some tribute to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31895602/ansible-filter-a-list-by-its-attributes) question, you can try this:

```
- name: Create Launch Configuration
  ec2_lc:
    ...
    security_groups: "{{ sg.results | selectattr('item.name','equalto',item) | join('',attribute='group_id') }}"
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a filter, that can make an aws api call for you dynamically.
For instance I have something like this in my vars/main.yml

```
public_sg_id: "{{ 'Public' |get_sg(public_vpc_id, aws_region) }}"
```

Here is the code for [get_sg](http://github.com/linuxdynasty/ld-ansible-filters/blob/master/filter_plugins/aws.py) filter.

```
import boto.ec2
from ansible import errors

def get_sg(name, vpc_id, region):
    connect = boto.ec2.connect_to_region(region)
    filter_by = {
        "tag-key": "Name",
        "tag-value": name,
        "vpc-id": vpc_id
    }
    sg_groups = connect.get_all_security_groups(filters=filter_by)
    if len(sg_groups) == 1:
        return sg_groups[0].id
    elif len(sg_groups) > 1:
        raise errors.AnsibleFilterError(
            "Too many results for {0}: {1}".format(
                name, ",".join(sg_groups)
            )
    )
    else:
        raise errors.AnsibleFilterError(
            "Security Group {0} was not found".format(name)
        )
```