# Ansible - get list of multiple attributes and do lineinfile

Tags: ansible

I've got multiple values under `mounts`, I want to have all 'mountpoints' of these attributes.

```
"mounts": {
        "/dev/sdb": {
            "fstype": "xfs",
            "mountpoint": "/my/point1",
            "opts": "defaults,_netdev",
            "partition": "/dev/sdb1",
            "state": "mounted"
        },
        "/dev/sdc": {
            "fstype": "xfs",
            "mountpoint": "/my/point2",
            "opts": "defaults,_netdev",
            "partition": "/dev/sdc1",
            "state": "mounted"
        },
        "/dev/sdd": {
            "fstype": "xfs",
            "mountpoint": "/my/point3",
            "opts": "defaults,_netdev",
            "partition": "/dev/sdd1",
            "state": "mounted"
```

How do I register the three mountpoints in memory for later use, so I get:

```
/my/point1, /my/point2, /my/point3
```

I want to place the values in `/etc/updatedb.conf` with `lineinfile`, so there should be no spacing.

My end result would look like; `cat /etc/updatedb.conf`

```
PRUNEPATHS = "/my/point1 /my/point2 /my/point3"
```

Currently, I use a template to copy pre-defined variables. But this is not dynamic enough.

I'm playing around how to get the right variables, but no success:

```
- debug: var=mount[all].mountpoints
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a list:

```
- debug: msg="{{ mounts.values() | map(attribute='mountpoint') | list }}"
```

Or a string:

```
- debug: msg="{{ mounts.values() | map(attribute='mountpoint') | list | join(' ') }}"
```

Comment: Yes. Very helpfull! Learning everyday :)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

You can get the join of the keys from `mounts` like this:

```
mounts: {{ mounts.keys()|join(', ') }}
```

---

(old answer that is not valid for this question)

as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31896249/2599522) describes, you can do

```
---
  - hosts: all

    tasks:
      - set_fact: mounts={{ ansible_mounts | map(attribute='device')|join(',')}}

      - debug: var=ansible_mounts
      - debug: var=mounts
```

sample output

```
ap test.yml -i hosts -l server

PLAY [all] *********************************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [server]

TASK [set_fact] ****************************************************************
ok: [server]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [server] => {
    "ansible_mounts": [
        {
            "device": "/dev/sda1",
            "fstype": "ext4",
            "mount": "/",
            "options": "rw,errors=remount-ro",
            "size_available": 2890289152,
            "size_total": 9376751616,
            "uuid": "N/A"
        },
        {
            "device": "/dev/sdb1",
            "fstype": "ext4",
            "mount": "/mnt/data1",
            "options": "rw",
            "size_available": 50684461056,
            "size_total": 200674758656,
            "uuid": "N/A"
        }
    ]
}

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [server] => {
    "mounts": "/dev/sda1,/dev/sdb1"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
server                    : ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Comment: Getting `undefined object` on my local file, because there is variable between mounts and mountpoint, which is different each block.


`/dev/sdb` `/dev/sdc` `/dev/sdd`

Comment: you might need to tweak that. I usually try with `ansible all -m setup` and then find the exact json item i need. Whats your ansible version ?

Comment: Version I'm using is v2.1.2.0
I set the variables myself. Will look in -m setup

Comment: so the `"mounts"` you are using its not the `ansible_facts` mounts ?

Comment: The formatting in a comment windows isn't the best.
I set the vars myself:


`vars:
    mounts:
      /dev/sdb:
        partition: ..
        mountpoint: /my/point1
        state: ..
        opts: ..
        fstype: ..
      /dev/sdc:
        partition: ..
        mountpoint: /my/point2
        state: ..
        opts: ..
        fstype: ..
      /dev/sdd:
        partition: ..
        mountpoint: /my/point2
        state: ..
        opts: ..
        fstype: ..`

If unclear, you can PM me.