# Ansible: filter a list by its attributes using variable

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I'm having a problem to filter a list by it's attribute using variable.

Let's say I have variable "network" register in ansible.

```
{
    "addresses": {
    "private_ext": [
        {
            "type": "fixed",
            "addr": "172.16.2.100"
        }
    ],
    "private_man": [
        {
            "type": "fixed",
            "addr": "172.16.1.100"
        },
        {
            "type": "floating",
            "addr": "10.90.80.10"
        }
        {
            "type": "floatingXYZ",
            "addr": "10.20.30.10"
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

and I want to use something like this

```
- debug: msg="{{ network.addresses | json_query(\"private_man[?type=='^${PATTERN}$'].addr\") }}"
```

or this

```
- debug: msg={{ network.addresses.private_man | selectattr("type", "match", "^${PATTERN}$") | map(attribute='addr') | join(',') }}
```

but the search pattern is stored in variable PATTERN with value "floating" and I want to find the exact value (not with value floatingXYZ).

Almost the same problem was described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31895602/ansible-filter-a-list-by-its-attributes/31896249#31896249), but without the variable part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use string concatenation:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ network.addresses.private_man | selectattr('type', 'match', '^'+PATTERN+'$') | map(attribute='addr') | join(',') }}"
  vars:
    PATTERN: floating
```