# How to do multi-conditional loops with Ansible?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have `roles` and `users`. I would like to loop over my `roles` for `users` that contains the `state=present`.

```
iam_roles:
  - name: "developers-role"
    assume_role_policy_document: "developers"
    state: present
    managed_policy:
      - arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXX:policy/CustomAmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess

  - name: "bigdata-role"
    assume_role_policy_document: "bigdata"
    state: present
    managed_policy:
      - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEC2ReadOnlyAccess
      - arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXX:policy/CustomAmazonRDSReadOnlyAccess

 iam_users:
   - name: test-user-1
     state: present
     groups: [developers]
     password:
     slack_name:
     access_key_state: create

   - name: test-user-2
     state: present
     groups: [developers]
     password:
     slack_name:
```

I'm trying *filter* and get only the `users` with the `state=present` and use it on my `when` clause, but no luck so far.

```
- name: Loop all the present users
  debug: msg={{ item }}
  when: "{{ item.state == 'present' }}"
  with_items: "{{ iam_users }}"
  tags: always
  register: present_users

- set_fact:
    iam_present_users: "{{ present_users.results }}"
  tags: always

- name: Show only present users, ideally
  debug: msg="{{ iam_present_users }}"
  tags: always

- name: Manage AWS IAM Roles
  iam_role:
    name: "{{ item.name }}"
    assume_role_policy_document: "{{ lookup('template', policies_path + '/assume-role/' + item.assume_role_policy_document + '.json') }}"
    state: "{{ item.state }}"
    managed_policy: "{{ item.managed_policy }}"
  when: "{{ item.managed_policy is defined and iam_present_users is defined }}"
  with_items: "{{ iam_roles }}"
  tags: manage_roles
```

Comment: Please have a look at the help center https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and take to heart the advice "**Pretend you're talking to a busy colleague**". Do you expect people to spend their time on trying to figure out what (and where in the code you posted) there is any relation between `iam_roles` and `iam_users `? How many minutes do you expect every single SO reader to spend on that?

Comment: Could you please be more specific? What you don't understand in my question? Yes, I have read the https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. As you said, my colleague has a technical understand of Ansible and Jinja2, thus my straight forward question. However, it might be lacking some information you might need in order to help me. Thus my inquiry. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ansible: filter a list by its attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31895602/ansible-filter-a-list-by-its-attributes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use of a `debug` statement to try to extract users seems odd.  If you want to select objects from a list based on the value of an attribute, your best choice is probably the Jinja2 `selectattr` filter.  For example, given this input:

```
iam_users:
  - name: test-user-1
    state: present
    groups: [developers]
    password:
    slack_name:
    access_key_state: create

  - name: test-user-2
    state: present
    groups: [developers]
    password:
    slack_name:

  - name: test-user-3
    state: absent
    groups: [developers]
    password:
    slack_name:
```

You could use this `set_fact` task:

```
- set_fact:
    iam_present_users: "{{ iam_users|selectattr('state', 'equalto', 'present')|list }}"
```

Which would result in `iam_present_users` containing:

```
"iam_present_users": [
    {
        "access_key_state": "create", 
        "groups": [
            "developers"
        ], 
        "name": "test-user-1", 
        "password": null, 
        "slack_name": null, 
        "state": "present"
    }, 
    {
        "groups": [
            "developers"
        ], 
        "name": "test-user-2", 
        "password": null, 
        "slack_name": null, 
        "state": "present"
    }
]
```

See [the jinja documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#builtin-filters) for the stock list of filters, and [the ansible documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_filters.html) for a list of filters specific to ansible.

Comment: Hi @larsks, thank you for your answer! It's exactly what I need! The usage of `debug` was wrong indeed, I'm still learning Ansible :)

Comment: @techraf, while I agree that the question may have been a little unclear I think I've at least been able to point the OP in the right direction. It's okay if there's a little ambiguity here and there.

Comment: @larsks What you wrote in the answer filters `iam_users` list to a list which is identical to `iam_users` -- how does it change anything in the `iam_role` task? How does it point anyone anywhere?

Comment: @techgraf the result is not identical to `iam_users`.  Please take a look a the example data *in my answer* and the resulting output. The OP said, "I'm trying filter and get only the users with the state=present ", and that is exactly what this solution does.

Comment: @larsks I was referring to `iam_users` given in the OP question -- the result of the filter is identical to the source. I don't get what you are trying to defend. You posted a duplicate answer to of a [well-known question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31895602/2947502) under a question whose wording asks for something completely different (if anything at all). It's just contributing to creating a mess.

Comment: @techraf Chill man! Larsks have really helped me with his answer! I saw the answer you suggested to be a possible duplicate, but I didn't know how I could apply it in my case. I'm sure that neither me or Lars is trying to create a mess ;)