# Ansible: from a list of directories, filter out only existing dirs

Tags: linux, ansible, provisioning, ansible-facts

I'm trying to create an Ansible playbook that will check a list of directories, and filter that list to only include existing directories, and store that list to a variable (fact?).  In addition to storing a filtered list of existing directories, I'd also like to store the first found existing directory to a different variable.

I'm having some difficulty getting that to work and feel like I'm making it more difficult that it should be. Any suggestions?

```
- hosts: all
  vars:
   my_dirs:
   - "/a/"
   - "/b/"
   - "/c/"
  tasks:

  - name: Checking existing file name
    stat:
      path: "{{ item }}"
    with_items: "{{ my_dirs }}"
    register: check_file_name

  - name: Set fact
    set_fact:
       existing_paths: "{{ item.stat.path }}"
    with_items:
      "{{ check_file_name.results }}"
    when: item.stat.exists | default(False) | bool
```

Comment: What happens when you try this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ansible: filter a list by its attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31895602/ansible-filter-a-list-by-its-attributes)

Comment: When I ran the above, the "existing_paths" var would just contain a single path.  Each loop of the with_items would re-set the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you almost got it working but might require some change in the playbook as below the results collected in an array:

```
  - set_fact: existing_paths="{{ [] }}"

  - name: Set fact
    set_fact:
       existing_paths: "{{ existing_paths +[item.stat.path] }}"
    with_items:
      "{{ check_file_name.results }}"
    when: item.stat.exists
```

Comment: Thank you, that seemed to work very well!  I never would have thought of creating and appending to the list like that.