# Ansible: no filter named 'selectattr'

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-template

I'm taking a foray into the world of Ansible.  Right now, I have a task where I am trying to say:

> If any of a list of files don't exist, then run this task

To accomplish this,  I have this piece of code right here.

```
- name: Check if certificate already exists.
  stat:
    path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/{{ item }}/cert.pem
  with_items: "{{ cert_domains }}"  
  register: letsencrypt_cert

- name: Create the certs
  raw: certbot --nginx --noninteractive -d "{{ cert_domains.0 }}" -d "{{ cert_domains.1 }}"
  register: certbot_create
  changed_when: certbot_create.stdout
  when:
    - "{{ letsencrypt_cert.results|selectattr('stat','false') | length > 0 }}"
```

However, when I run my process it greets me with the following error:

```
"msg": "The conditional check '{{ 
letsencrypt_cert.results|selectattr('stat','false') | length > 1 }}' failed.     
The error was: template error while templating string: no filter named 
'selectattr'. String: {{ letsencrypt_cert.results|selectattr('stat','false') 
| length > 0 }}\
```

In something like LINQ, i would do something like this:

```
  list.where( n => n.equals(false)).Count() > 0
```

What could be going wrong?

For the sake of thoroughness, here are my versions:

ansible 2.4.2.0

python version = 2.6.9

Name: Jinja2 Version: 2.7.2

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `selectattr` is available since Jinja2 2.7+, so it seems that you may have some python package mess on your system, so Ansible uses wrong Jinja2.

Comment: Regardless of the `selectattr` error message you get, `selectattr('stat','false')` makes no sense. See [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31896249/2947502).

Comment: Please do not add the answer to the question. You can answer your own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had installed Jinja2 using 'pip install jinja2'. What I needed to do was

```
'sudo yum install python-jinja2'
```

to get things working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- name: Create the certs
  raw: certbot --nginx --noninteractive -d "{{ cert_domains.0 }}" -d "{{ cert_domains.1 }}"
  register: certbot_create
  changed_when: certbot_create.stdout
  when:
    - letsencrypt_cert.results | selectattr('stat', 'defined') | map(attribute='stat') | selectattr('exists', 'equalto', false) | list | length > 0
```