# setting variables on asnible with 3 conditions

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, autoscaling

earlier I have these condition on my ansible task.yml which I verified working, basically when the parameter is `dev` then the `ASG` is set to "`awseb-e-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup-DEV`", if not then ASG will be set to the `uat` `ASG` which is "`awseb-e-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup-UAT`"

```
 - set_fact:
  ASG: "{{ (env == 'dev') | ternary('awseb-e-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxj-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup-DEV', 'awseb-e-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxj-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup-UAT') }}"
```

My question is what if I add more choice on the logic, say when the parameter used on the playbook is `prod` then use the `ASG` "`awseb-e-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxj-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup-PROD`"? I have this idea but not sure if it will work, let me know your expert advices

```
 - set_fact:
  ASG: "{{ (env == 'dev') | ternary('awseb-e-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxj-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup-DEV'}}"
 - set_fact:
  ASG: "{{ (env == 'uat') | ternary('awseb-e-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxj-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup-UAT'}}"
 - set_fact:
  ASG: "{{ (env == 'prod') | ternary('awseb-e-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxj-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup-PROD'}}"
```

Comment: "*I have this idea but not sure if it will work*" ー how about trying?

Comment: didnt worked, gave me an error = ternary() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)

Comment: Create a data structure and use [the most voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31896249/2947502) under the dup-target to get the corresponding value for the one you are searching.