# registering stat result with_items doing task if stat result exists

Tags: ansible

I am new to ansible and have exhausted my forum searches.  I cannot seem to find an answer for this issue I am having with `with_items` and `when`.  *The playbook as it is now will run*, but it results in failed messages "src file does not exist" for every path in the list that does not exist on that machine.

Since, this is being run against several machines, that's a lot of failed (red) messages that mean nothing.   I thought the `when` statement would only run the task IF the `statresult` existed.  This is not the case.

Basically what I am trying to do is check several machines to see if these two paths exist.  If they do, create a symlink for each one.  All the paths to check in are different.  Right now I have:

```
---
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - name: Check that domains exist
    stat:
      path: '/path/to/the/domain/{{ item.domainpath }}'
      get_attributes: no
      get_checksum: no
      get_md5: no
      get_mime: no
    register: item.statresult
    with_items:
      - { domainpath: 'path1/', statresult: 'stat_result_path1' }
      - { domainpath: 'path2/', statresult: 'stat_result_path2' }
      - { domainpath: 'path3/', statresult: 'stat_result_path3' }
  - name: Create symlink for bin on existing domain machines
    file:
      src: '/path/to/the/domain/{{ item.srcbin }}'
      dest: /path/new/symlink_bin_link
      state: link
    with_items:
        - { srcbin: 'path1/bin/', domainexists: 'stat_result_path1.stat.exists' }
        - { srcbin: 'path2/bin/', domainexists: 'stat_result_path2.stat.exists' }
        - { srcbin: 'path3/bin/', domainexists: 'stat_result_path3.stat.exists' }
    when: item.domainexists
    ignore_errors: yes
  - name: Create symlink for config on existing domain machines
    file:
      src: '/path/to/the/domain/{{ item.srcconfig }}'
      dest: /path/new/symlink_config_link
      state: link
    with_items:
        - { srcconfig: 'path1/config/', domainexists: 'stat_result_path1.stat.exists' }
        - { srcconfig: 'path2/config/', domainexists: 'stat_result_path2.stat.exists' }
        - { srcconfig: 'path3/config/', domainexists: 'stat_result_path3.stat.exists' }
    when: item.domainexists
    ignore_errors: yes
```

I have to use `ignore_errors` because otherwise it will not go to the second task. I have tried to use `when: item.domainexists == true` but that results in the task getting skipped even when it matches a path that exists.

Even if the `when` statement iterates over every `with_items`, it should not matter because as long as it matches one, it should do the task correctly?

Comment: `register: item.statresult` is nonsensical in Ansible. You need to work on your first task before proceeding further to the one with `when` condition.

Comment: @techraf is right on that. I've updated my answer below to reflect that info.

Answer (score 2):

This is how your playbook should look like:

```
---
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: Check that domains exist
      stat:
        path: /path/to/the/domain/{{ item }}
      loop:
        - path1
        - path2
        - path3
      register: my_stat

    - name: Ensure symlinks are created for bin on existing domain machines
      file:
        src: /path/new/symlink_bin_link
        dest: /path/to/the/domain/{{ item }}/bin
        state: link
      loop: "{{ my_stat.results | selectattr('stat.exists') | map(attribute='item') | list }}"

    - name: Ensure symlinks are created for config on existing domain machines
      file:
        src: /path/new/symlink_config_link
        dest: /path/to/the/domain/{{ item }}/config
        state: link
      loop: "{{ my_stat.results | selectattr('stat.exists') | map(attribute='item') | list }}"
```

Explanation:

- `register: item.statresult` is a nonsensical construct in Ansible, you should provide [a name of a variable as a parameter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#registered-variables)
- that variable [will contain a list of results](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#using-register-with-a-loop) for any task running in a loop
- you should process that list (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31896249/2947502) to learn about `selectattr` and `map`) to get a list of the paths which exist (only)
- you should loop over that filtered-and-mapped list

Also: `src` and `dest` should be defined the other way round for symlinks than in your code.

---

Further, you can combine the last two tasks into one by adding a `product` filter to the iterable definition.

Comment: Excellent!  Thank you very much!  I will definitely dive into the selectattr and map functions to learn more.