# Ansible map dictionary items to a list

Tags: python, ansible, jinja2

You have a list of ansible dictionaries:

```
domains:
  - { domain: example.com, cert: cert1.pem }
  - { domain: example.in, cert: cert2.pem }
```

how do you produce joined array list in a jinja2 template from domains only?

```
domains=example.com,example.in
```

Comment: Sorry, there is nothing in your question, nor answer, that is not in the duplicate one (which you even linked).

Comment: I wasn't able to find this on stackoverflow using keywords in title. The linked answer explains filtering, not how to convert dictionary items to list, specifically.

Comment: And what is the result of filtering the list? A list.　Besides you wrote "*You have ansible dictionary*", but what follows is a definition of a list in YAML.

Comment: @techraf, sorry there is nothing in the "duplicate" question that is understandable by a human being to answer the question asked by Julius.

Answer (score 9):

```
domains={{ domains | map(attribute='domain') | list | join(",") }}
```

[Ansible: filter a list by its attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31895602/ansible-filter-a-list-by-its-attributes)

https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/24338