# Ansible select sub list from list of dictionaries with matching regex values

Tags: ansible, yaml

I have a yml list that is similar to the following:

```
name_ips: 
  rr: [
        {
            "name": "db1-137.com", 
            "ip": "1.1.1.1"
        }, 
        {
            "name": "core1-137.com", 
            "ip": "2.2.2.2"
        }, 
        {
            "name": "core0-139.com", 
            "ip": "3.3.3.3"
        }, 
        {
            "name": "db0-147.com", 
            "ip": "4.4.4.4"
        }
      ]
```

Using ansible I want to select the items in this list with `name` values matching the regex:

```
regexp: ".*137.com"
```

My end result should look similar to the following, which I want to be able to set using the `set_fact` module:

```
[
    {
        "name": "db1-137.com", 
        "ip": "1.1.1.1"
    }, 
    {
        "name": "core1-137.com", 
        "ip": "2.2.2.2"
    }
]
```

How can I achieve this sub-list select operation?

**Update**:

I found I can return a single value if I state the exact name:

```
- debug: msg="{{ name_ips | json_query(\"rr[?name=='core0-139.com']\") }}"`
```

Returns:

```
    {
        "name": "core0-139.com", 
        "ip": "3.3.3.3"
    }
```

This is a start, but I would still like to use a regex for this search.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ansible: filter a list by its attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31895602/ansible-filter-a-list-by-its-attributes)

Comment: That solution is very close, thanks!  However, it does not utilize a regex.

Comment: [Oh really?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31896249)