# Ansible/Jinja2 - How to write jinja if statement that queries if a variable is defined?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I am trying to write certain variables into a configuration file depending on the existence of a variable in another file.

In essence, I have the following:

```
[servers]
server-0 ansible_host=192.168.1.11 zone=0 sriov=true
server-1 ansible_host=192.168.1.12 zone=1 sriov=true
```

and I'm trying the following:

```
{% if groups['servers'] | map('extract', hostvars) | selectattr('sriov', 'defined') %}
[pci]
....
{% endif %}
```

This works fine when `sriov=true`, but it also adds the variables when:

```
[servers]
server-0 ansible_host=192.168.1.11 zone=0
server-1 ansible_host=192.168.1.12 zone=1
```

What would be the proper syntax to make sure that these variables only get written when the sriov variable is defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression below returns a list of selectors to be used in map()

```
msg: groups['servers'] | map('extract', hostvars) | selectattr('sriov', 'defined')
```

Without evaluation, this expression returns something like this

```
"msg": "<generator object select_or_reject at 0x7f52f65cfe60>"
```

I don't know how this might cast to Boolean.

If map() is used

```
msg: "{{ groups['test_jails']|map('extract', hostvars)|selectattr('sriov', 'defined')|map(attribute='inventory_hostname')|list }}"
```

absence of the "*sriov*" attributes gives:

```
"msg": []
```

If "*sriov*" attributes are defined

```
[test_jails]
test_01 sriov=true
test_02 sriov=false
test_03 sriov=true
```

the result is

```
"msg": [
    "test_01", 
    "test_02", 
    "test_03"
]
```

A lot of hints are available in [Ansible: filter a list by its attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31895602/ansible-filter-a-list-by-its-attributes).